# how to display fontawesome icon on multiple images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So what i'm trying to accomplish is i want to add share icon on multiple images where each image will have different link however as far as the icon goes i want it to be on center of all of the images below is sample of my code any help will be appreciated thanks.
link for  http://jsfiddle.net/nhxjvmhh/

HTML

```
<div class="movieicon">
    <a href="v/link">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-l2d24l8Zir4/Txh8bYhN6rI/AAAAAAAAC3s/lWtdZuBS-bc/w500-h350-no/24.gif" width=300 height=180 />
    <span  class="fa fa-share-square-o"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fa-share-square-o:hover {
    color:#4099FF;
}
.fa-share-square-o{
    color: #cccccc;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to absolutely position the icon *relative* to the parent element.

Use `text-align: center` for horizontal centering, and `top: 50%`/`transform: translateY(-50%)` for vertical centering.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/tysvvzjn/)

```
.movieicon {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.movieicon a {
    display: block;
}
.movieicon .fa-share-square-o {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```